FFMPEG drawText with fontSize scale "bounce" animation
I'm trying to add a "bounce" animation on a section of text from a known startTime and endTime
My initial approach has been to split the start and end times into a first half ( scale up ) and second half (scale down)
const start1 = start;
const start2 = start + (end - start) / 2;
const end1 = start + (end - start) / 2;
const end2 = end;

And then combine 2 ffmpeg filters
First
fontsize = 25 + (10 * (t - ${start1}) * (${end1} - ${start1}) / (${start1} - ${end1}) + ${start1})
Second
fontsize = 25 + (10 * (1 - (t - ${start2}) ) * (${end2} - ${start2}) / (${end2} - ${start2}) + ${start2})
My math could be off but both commands appear to render the text at an initial size, and scale down further than I want.
Is this possible?
Thanks!

try sinus: :fontsize='25+30*if(between(t,$start,$end),sin(PI*(t-$start)/($end-$start)),0)'
